# Compare two images using one of that as reference

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need to compare two images and get RGB differences using one of that as reference:

[image: Reference Image]
[image: Image after changes]

I'm using this code,

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

img1 = Image.open("sagitale1pos.png")
img2 = Image.open("sagitale1pre.png")

diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)

if diff.getbbox():
    diff.show()
```

but it returns all differences between images, and I want to see only the changes in image 2.

Thanks for help

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by :"all differences between images, and I want to see only the changes in image 2.".  If there is a difference between the two images, isn't that a change in image 2?

Comment: The code I used shows me, for example, a specific color in image 1 that does not exist in image 2, like red in left-bottom area. In this case, the color red should not appear.

Comment: The red appears in image 1 and not in image 2, okay but this is a difference in the images. What criteria is used to decide what changes are important?

Comment: You are right. Thanks for comments